# How to read inline data written in a store from a controller in Sencha Touch 2.0 mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, store, sencha-touch-2

I am learning about Sencha so i have very basilar question.
I am trying to build a simple mvc application, with controller, views model and store.

I have this nmodel

```
Ext.define('rpc.model.Studenti', {
Extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'cognome', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'previsione', type: 'string' }
]
});
```

this store (with inline data)

```
Ext.define('rpc.store.Studenti', {
model: 'rpc.model.Studenti',
storeId: 'gruppoStore',
autoLoad: true,
data: [
    {cognome: 'uno', previsione: 'aaa'},
    {cognome: 'due', previsione: 'bbb'},
    {cognome: 'tre', previsione: 'ccc'}
]
});
```

the controller

```
Ext.define('rpc.controller.Home', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores: ['Studenti'],
models: ['Studenti'],
views: ['home.Fila','home.Griglia','home.Previsio'],
store: 'gruppoStore',
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'griglia button': {
            tap: this.faqualcosa
        }
    });
},
faqualcosa: function(button){
    ...
    var gruppoStoreMgr=this.getStudentiStore();

    alert (gruppoStoreMgr.count());
    for (var key in gruppoStoreMgr) {           
        //alert (key);
    }
    alert (gruppoStoreMgr.storeId);
    alert (gruppoStoreMgr.isInstance);
    //alert (gruppoStoreMgr.data);
    alert (gruppoStoreMgr.autoLoad);
    for (var key in gruppoStoreMgr.data[0]) {
        //alert ("0"+key);
    }
    for (var key in gruppoStoreMgr.data[1]) {
        //alert ("1"+key);
    }
}
});
```

Please, what is the right way to access in function faqualcosa to the store data?
I've been able to have something like an instance (sure it is very near...) of the model with var gruppoStoreMgr=this.getStudentiStore(); but i have no trace of the data i've written in the store ("uno", "due"....). How to get that data? How to have in a controller funcion an object who refers to the real data in the store?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.getStudentiStore().data.items
```

That is the most direct way to get to the data. It returns an array of the model records. If that's what you're looking for.

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.geStudentiStore().getCount(); i++ ) {
   var record = this.getStudentiStore().getAt(i)
   console.log(record.get('cognome'));
}
```

That should print out all the "cognomes"

Comment: The real problem was a missing in the store file. I've missed to extend the store base. Adding the row  extend: 'Ext.data.Store' i've started to have things working on. Anyway thanks for your answer stan229